# Using TextField for setProxyHost and setProxyPort in Swift

Tags: objective-c, macos, proxy, asihttprequest

I use ASIHTTPRequest in my mac os project and I want to use text field for setProxyHost and setProxyPort. I added two textfield.

```
[request1 setProxyHost:_textofproxyhost.text];
[request1 setProxyPort:_textofproxyport.text];
```

I tried it. I think I need to use button but I don't know how to use button there.

Comment: What did you try? What exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @rocky I wanted to control proxy by 2 text field and button. But I have no idea how I can do it.